# Properly Exposing Geth RPC in 2020

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, geth-debugging, rpc

With the default allowed `["net", "web3", "eth"]`, I want to expose Geth 1.9.21-stable RPC to another machine.

In config.html I set `HTTPVirtualHosts = ["*"]`.

The cmd to start geth (via systemd) is `geth --nousb --config /path/to/config.toml --http --http.addr "0.0.0.0"`

**Do I need to use `--http --http.addr "0.0.0.0"` in the start cmd or is there a way to do this in config.toml?** (AFAIK `--nousb` has to be a start cmd parameter)

This has been asked before, but things change and all the answers are a few years old.

PS: the perimeter firewall handles blocking access to RPC from outside the LAN. It would be nice to specify in Geth what is the only LAN IP that can use the RPC, but it is not necessary.

Comment: They renamed `--rpcSomething` to `--http.SomeOtherThing`.

Comment: Correct, updated the answer